# Flutter - Add a Tappable Icon to the TextField label - onTap not executing

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-textformfield

I'm trying all sorts of things to add a little tappable icon to a textField that moves up and down with the floating label:

[image]

However, everything I try just focuses the text field on tap, and does not execute the `onTap` event of the icon, so the icon is not tappable.

I tried a Stack, but onTap did not execute. Then I tried [this tutorial](https://medium.com/flutter/how-to-float-an-overlay-widget-over-a-possibly-transformed-ui-widget-1d15ca7667b6) using `CompositedTransformTarget` and `CompositedTransformFollower` but still the same result of focusing the TextField and not executing the onTap. What am I doing wrong?

`CompositedTransformTarget` and `CompositedTransformFollower` code:

TextField:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:reactive_forms/reactive_forms.dart';
import 'package:vepo/src/_common/constants/presentation/padding.dart';
import 'package:vepo/src/_common/utils/form_utils.dart';
import 'package:vepo/src/presentation/widgets/form_fields/text_fields/field_length_counter/pulse_on_change_field_length_counter_widget.dart';
import 'package:vepo/src/presentation/widgets/form_fields/text_fields/text_field/text_field_vm.dart';

class VpTextField extends ReactiveFormField<String, String> {
  VpTextField(
      {String? formControlName,
      FormControl<String>? formControl,
      this.hintText,
      required this.context,
      this.labelText,
      this.label,
      this.maxLines = 1,
      bool Function(AbstractControl<dynamic>)? showErrors,
      this.hintMaxLines = 1,
      this.textCapitalization = TextCapitalization.sentences,
      this.textInputType = TextInputType.text,
      this.textColor,
      this.maxLength,
      this.focusNode,
      bool hasFocus = false,
      this.textAlign = TextAlign.left,
      this.readonly = false,
      this.shouldObscureText = false,
      this.form,
      this.onSubmitted,
      ControlValueAccessor<String, String>? valueAccessor,
      Key? key,
      this.textInputAction = TextInputAction.next,
      this.nextField,
      this.inputFormatters,
      Map<String, String> Function(AbstractControl<dynamic>)?
          validationMessages,
      this.onFocusChange})
      : super(
            key: key,
            formControlName: formControlName,
            valueAccessor: valueAccessor,
            formControl: formControl,
            builder: (ReactiveFormFieldState<String, String> field) {
              assert(!(label != null && labelText != null),
                  'Declaring both label and labelText is not supported.');
              return Consumer(builder: ((context, ref, child) {
                final vm = ref.watch(textMultipleFieldVmProvider);

                WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                  vm.showIndicator(context);
                });
                return FocusScope(
                    child: Focus(
                        onFocusChange: (isFocused) {
                          hasFocus = isFocused;
                          if (onFocusChange != null) {
                            onFocusChange(isFocused);
                          }
                          // ignore: invalid_use_of_protected_member
                          field.setState(() {});
                        },
                        child: Stack(clipBehavior: Clip.none, children: [
                          ReactiveTextField<dynamic>(
                            maxLines: maxLines,
                            focusNode: focusNode,
                            showErrors: showErrors ??
                                (control) => control.invalid && control.touched,
                            textCapitalization: textCapitalization,
                            keyboardType: textInputType,
                            textInputAction: textInputAction,
                            onEditingComplete: onSubmitted ??
                                (() {
                                  if (form != null && nextField != null) {
                                    form.focus(nextField);
                                  }
                                }),
                            inputFormatters: inputFormatters,
                            formControlName: formControlName,
                            formControl: formControl,
                            obscureText: shouldObscureText,
                            validationMessages: validationMessages,
                            maxLength: maxLength,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                contentPadding: readonly
                                    ? const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(32, 0, 12, 8)
                                    : null,
                                fillColor: readonly ? Colors.transparent : null,
                                errorMaxLines: 5,
                                suffixIconConstraints: const BoxConstraints(
                                  minWidth: 2,
                                  minHeight: 2,
                                ),
                                suffixIcon: ReactiveStatusListenableBuilder(
                                  formControlName: formControlName,
                                  formControl: formControl,
                                  builder: (context, control, child) {
                                    return control.pending
                                        ? SizedBox(
                                            width: 90,
                                            height: 60,
                                            child: Stack(children: [
                                              Positioned(
                                                top: SMALL_PAD,
                                                right: SUFFIX_ICON_PAD,
                                                child:
                                                    CircularProgressIndicator(
                                                        backgroundColor: Theme
                                                                .of(context)
                                                            .primaryColorDark),
                                              )
                                            ]))
                                        : Container(width: 0);
                                  },
                                ),
                                alignLabelWithHint: true,
                                labelStyle:
                                    FormUtils.labelStyle(context, hasFocus),
                                hintText: hintText,
                                hintMaxLines: hintMaxLines,
                                labelText: readonly ? null : labelText,
                                label: label != null
                                    ? CompositedTransformTarget(
                                        link: vm.layerLink,
                                        child: Container(
                                            width: vm.slideWidth,
                                            height: vm.slideHeight,
                                            color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.2),
                                            child: GestureDetector(
                                                onTap: () {
                                                  print('tap');
                                                },
                                                child: label)))
                                    : null,
                                counterText: ''),
                            textAlign: textAlign,
                          ),
                          if (readonly)
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(55, 0, 0, 0),
                              child: Text(labelText!,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      height: 0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                                      fontSize: 14.0,
                                      color: Theme.of(context)
                                          .colorScheme
                                          .primaryContainer)),
                            ),
                          if (maxLength != null && hasFocus)
                            Positioned(
                                top: -10,
                                right: -10,
                                child: VpPulseOnChangeFieldLengthCounter(
                                    field: field, maxLength: maxLength))
                        ])));
              }));
            });

  final BuildContext? context;
  final TextAlign textAlign;
  final bool shouldObscureText;
  final String? hintText;
  final String? labelText;
  final Widget? label;
  final int? maxLength;
  final void Function(bool)? onFocusChange;
  final void Function()? onSubmitted;
  final Color? textColor;
  final bool readonly;
  final FocusNode? focusNode;
  final TextInputType? textInputType;

  /// This is usually used to transform the text to lower case for emails ect.
  final List<TextInputFormatter>? inputFormatters;

  /// This is only required when setting the next field to focus on.
  final FormGroup? form;

  /// This is only required when setting the next field to focus on.
  final String? nextField;
  final int? maxLines;
  final int? hintMaxLines;

  final TextCapitalization textCapitalization;

  /// This is to be 'next' if not the last field, and 'done' when is the last field.
  final TextInputAction textInputAction;

  @override
  ReactiveFormFieldState<String, String> createState() =>
      ReactiveFormFieldState<String, String>();
}
```

TextFieldViewmodel:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

final textMultipleFieldVmProvider = Provider<TextFieldVm>((provider) {
  return TextFieldVm();
});

class TextFieldVm {
  final double indicatorWidth = 24.0;
  final double indicatorHeight = 300.0;
  final double slideHeight = 200.0;
  final double slideWidth = 400.0;

  final LayerLink layerLink = LayerLink();
  OverlayEntry? overlayEntry;
  Offset? indicatorOffset;

  void updateIndicator(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    indicatorOffset = getIndicatorOffset(details.localPosition);
    overlayEntry?.markNeedsBuild();
  }

  void hideIndicator(DragEndDetails details) {
    overlayEntry?.remove();
  }

  Offset getIndicatorOffset(Offset dragOffset) {
    final double x = (dragOffset.dx - (indicatorWidth / 2.0))
        .clamp(0.0, slideWidth - indicatorWidth);
    final double y = (slideHeight - indicatorHeight) / 2.0;
    return Offset(x, y);
  }

  void showIndicator(BuildContext context) {
    overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Positioned(
          top: 0.0,
          left: 0.0,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: indicatorWidth,
            height: indicatorHeight,
            child: Indicator(offset: Offset(0, 21), link: layerLink),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
    Overlay.of(context)?.insert(overlayEntry!);
  }
}

class Indicator extends StatelessWidget {
  Indicator({Key? key, required this.link, required this.offset})
      : super(key: key);

  final LayerLink link;
  final Offset offset;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CompositedTransformFollower(
        offset: offset,
        link: link,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => print('tap'),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A label is not clickable, as a click is meant to shift it upwards.

You might find a workaround, but a simpler solution might be to use a `suffixIcon`:

```dart
TextField(  
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "label text",
    suffixIcon: IconButton(
      onPressed: () => print('yay'),
      icon: Icon(Icons.question_mark),
    ),
  ),
))
```

[image]

Comment: Yep... The TextField focusNode seems extremely hard to override for a small portion of the TextField. Using `InputDecoration.prefixIcon`.

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this:

```
 onTap: () {print('tap');},
```